# Core Data swift3 same primaryKey but different objectId in picker

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data

I'm an absolute newbie with Swift and Core Data.

I created a two Entity learning app, nothing special.

I'm stuck in finding why (AFAICT) my "Persona" picker objects in my "Medicina" Entity are different from the ones shown directly in the "Persona" Core Data table; since adding a **predicate** to filter the "Persona" Core Data table using the data obtained from the mentioned picker **always return 0 elements**.

## Details:

The Personas Core Data Table shows all the entities already added to the app, with no problems and It's possible to edit them.

When the following code in "PersonaTableViewController" gets executed:

```
...

try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()

...
```

The logs show:

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZCREATEDAT, t0.ZFECHANACIMIENTO, t0.ZMODIFIEDAT, t0.ZNOMBRE, t0.ZPESO FROM ZPERSONA t0 ORDER BY t0.ZCREATEDAT
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0006s
CoreData: annotation: fetch using NSSQLiteStatement <0x1c029abd0> on entity 'Persona' with sql text 'SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZCREATEDAT, t0.ZFECHANACIMIENTO, t0.ZMODIFIEDAT, t0.ZNOMBRE, t0.ZPESO FROM ZPERSONA t0 ORDER BY t0.ZCREATEDAT' returned 9 rows with values: (
    "<Persona: 0x1c029a900> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd000000000040004 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Persona: 0x1c029a950> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd000000000080004 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p2> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Persona: 0x1c029b6c0> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd0000000000c0004 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p3> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Persona: 0x1c029a810> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd000000000100004 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p4> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Persona: 0x1c029a860> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd000000000140004 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p5> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Persona: 0x1c029b940> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd000000000180004 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p6> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Persona: 0x1c029a590> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd0000000001c0004 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p7> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Persona: 0x1c029a770> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd000000000200004 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p8> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Persona: 0x1c029b5d0> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd000000000240004 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p9> ; data: <fault>)"
)
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0062s for 9 rows.
```

Then, the user needs to select a "Persona" entity in the "Medicina" Entity. So, there is a Picker component.

The piker is populated with this fragment of code:

```
func personaPickerInit(pPersonaPicker: UIPickerView) {

    personaPicker.delegate = self

    guard let managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext else { return }

    let personasFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Persona")
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nombre", ascending: true)
    personasFetch.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    do {
        let personaPickerObjects = try managedObjectContext.fetch(personasFetch) as! [Persona]

...
```

On execution, it shows the following in the logs:

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZCREATEDAT, t0.ZFECHANACIMIENTO, t0.ZMODIFIEDAT, t0.ZNOMBRE, t0.ZPESO FROM ZPERSONA t0 ORDER BY t0.ZNOMBRE
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0003s
CoreData: annotation: fetch using NSSQLiteStatement <0x1c4096c60> on entity 'Persona' with sql text 'SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZCREATEDAT, t0.ZFECHANACIMIENTO, t0.ZMODIFIEDAT, t0.ZNOMBRE, t0.ZPESO FROM ZPERSONA t0 ORDER BY t0.ZNOMBRE' returned 9 rows with values: (
    "<Persona: 0x1c4093f60> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Persona: 0x1c4097070> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd000000000140002 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p5> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Persona: 0x1c4099a00> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd000000000180002 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p6> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Persona: 0x1c4099b90> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd0000000001c0002 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p7> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Persona: 0x1c4099be0> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd000000000200002 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p8> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Persona: 0x1c4099af0> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd000000000240002 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p9> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Persona: 0x1c4099c80> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd000000000100002 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p4> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Persona: 0x1c4099960> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd000000000080002 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p2> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Persona: 0x1c4099820> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd0000000000c0002 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p3> ; data: <fault>)"
)
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0020s for 9 rows.
```

When It's time to let the user see/edit the "Persona" details, I add a predicate in the `PersonaTableViewController` so it should show only one "Persona".

I tried passing around the whole objects in an array called `personasFiltradas` using the following predicate:

```
self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate =  NSPredicate(format: "self IN %@", self.personasFiltradas);
```

With the corresponding log:

```
CoreData: annotation: logically false fetch request <NSFetchRequest: 0x1c40ce770> (entity: Persona; predicate: (SELF IN {<Persona: 0x1c02994b0> (entity: Persona; id: 0xd000000000100002 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p4> ; data: {
    createdAt = "1509640324.844775";
    fechaNacimiento = 886399200;
    medicinas = "<relationship fault: 0x1c423c640 'medicinas'>";
    modifiedAt = 0;
    nombre = "ggjfghcb jggjfhh hgjfjdj hfghfhfj utility uutsyifgu uyffuftjg. I I iuuuhhu Hugh";
    peso = "207.8";
})}); sortDescriptors: ((
    "(createdAt, ascending, compare:)"
)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; ) short circuits.
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0000s for 0 rows.
```

Also tried passing around the `objectID`in an array called `personasFiltradasIds` using the following predicate:

```
self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate =  NSPredicate(format: "Persona.objectID IN %@", self.personasFiltradasIds);
```

The corresponding log shows:

```
CoreData: annotation: logically false fetch request <NSFetchRequest: 0x1c40cfea0> (entity: Persona; predicate: (Persona.objectID IN {0xd000000000100002 <x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p4>}); sortDescriptors: ((
    "(createdAt, ascending, compare:)"
)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; ) short circuits.
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0000s for 0 rows.
```

If you pay attention to both "log" entries shown before, You can see the same objects (paths like: `<x-coredata://77904C2D-4B98-47DE-8A14-20A6F1CEB491/Persona/p1>`) have different ObjectID's, so the grid is always empty since the ones in the table end with a "4" and the ones in the picker end with a "2". (In fact those "id's" keep changing. The problem is the ones on the picker are always different from the ones in the table)

I'm not sure if my diagnose is correct, but that is what I can see.

Any help finding why my code is not working would be greately appreciated

---

## Edit 1

Here I add the model.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work, but still can't understand why one controller fetches "different" Persona objects than the other: If I fetch the "Persona" object in the `MedicinaTableViewController` it doesn't directly correspond to one taken from `PersonaTableViewController`

I had to send the uri representation of a "Persona" objectID from `MedicinaTableViewController` to `PersonaTableViewController`

```
vc.personasFiltradasUris = [medicina.persona!.objectID.uriRepresentation()]
```

And then take the `managedObjectId` from `persistentStoreCoordinator` using the `forURIRepresentation` parameter in order to obtain the object again from the `managedObjectContext`: `object(with: oid)`

```
var personasDesdeUris: [Persona] = []

for i in self.personasFiltradasUris {

    let oid: NSManagedObjectID = self.persistentContainer.viewContext.persistentStoreCoordinator!.managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: i)!
personasDesdeUris.append(self.persistentContainer.viewContext.object(with: oid) as! Persona)

    print("+++++++ (PersTVC/ViewDidLoad/loadPersistentStores (Uris)) objid: ", oid, ", objid-UriRep: ", i)
}

self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate =  NSPredicate(format: "self in %@", personasDesdeUris);
```

If I do this in the `MedicinaTableViewController` and send an array of Persona objects, they still have the wrong objects to the `PersonaTableViewController` and thus an empty result.

Any explanations would be greatly appreciated.

---

## EDIT 1

Forgot to say that, in both controllers the Persona's `objectID.isTemporaryID` is always false. So that is not the reason.